# Is there a way to get an Ember model's hasMany children without specifying relationship name?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Say you have a model:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  addresses: DS.hasMany('App.Address')
```

I know I can grab the addresses by simply doing:

```
@get('model').get('addresses')
```

But say you have many models, each having one or more different hasMany relationships. Is there a way to *generically* grab the relationships?

Something like:

```
@get('model').get('hasMany')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an ember model class, you can get to it's of the relationships like:

var attributes = Ember.get(App.Post, 'attributes');
var relationships = Ember.get(App.Post, 'relationships');

If you don't know the type of model, you can replace `App.Post` with

```
var klass = model.get('constructor');
 //or based on your question
var klass = this.get('model.constructor');
```

Comment: Using your suggestion, I see that Ember.get(klass, 'relationships') returns a Ember.MapWithDefault. Its "values" property contains a hash of arrays, one of which contains an Object {kind: "hasMany", name: "addresses"}. So that I can accept your answer, how do you actually grab the hasMany relationships?